# How to copy all the files modified today using ANT script?

Tags: ant, scripting, salesforce, sfdc-migration-tool

I have below script which will give me number of files mentioned in my "count" field. What I want is to get all the files that were modified today.

```html
<project name="copy latest files test" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
 <classpath>
 <pathelement location="C:/apache-ant-1.9.6/lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
 </classpath>
</taskdef>
<!-- Create sub folder called classes -->
    <target name="createClassesFolder">
      <mkdir dir="tempFolder/classes"/>
    </target>
<!-- Copy contents of classes folder from source folder -->
    <target name="moveClassesFolder" depends="createClassesFolder">
  <copy toDir="tempFolder/classes" preservelastmodified="true">
     <last count="2">
     <sort>
     <date xmlns="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.comparators"/>
     <resources>
     <fileset dir="retrieveUnpackaged/classes"/>
     </resources>
     </sort>
     </last>
  </copy>

    </target>
</project>
```

I also want to get .xml file of the same files that were copied during the process. The reason to get .xml file is to use ANT migration tool once I have everything in other directory. How do I achieve that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. Below is the ANT script.

```
<property name="src.dir" value="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
<property name="dest.dir" value="tempFolder"/>

<target name="moveFolders" >
    <copy toDir="${dest.dir}">        
          <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
            <include name="*/**"/>              
            <date datetime="04/20/2016 10:35 AM" when="after"/>
          </fileset>      
    </copy>
```